# Replace words or words combinations with PHP regexp

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have map for replacement words:

```
$map = array(
  'word1' => 'replacement1',
  'word2 blah' => 'replacement 2',
  //...
);
```

I need to replace words in string. But replacement should be executed only when string is word:

- It is not in the middle of some other word ex. *textword1* will not be replaced with *replacement1* because it is part of another token.
- Separators must be saved, but words before/after them should be replaced.

I could split string with regexp to words but this does not work when there will be mapped values with few tokens (like *word2 blah*).

Comment: Not sure if it would do the job by its self, but you will likely want to look into the word boundary \b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$map = array(   'foo' => 'FOO',
                'over' => 'OVER');

// get the keys.
$keys = array_keys($map);

// get the values.
$values = array_values($map);

// surround each key in word boundary and regex delimiter
// also escape any regex metachar in the key
foreach($keys as &$key) {
        $key = '/\b'.preg_quote($key).'\b/';
}

// input string.    
$str = 'Hi foo over the foobar in stackoverflow';

// do the replacement using preg_replace                
$str = preg_replace($keys,$values,$str);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/k35DT)